# Se cortan los textos de mi base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Tengo una base de datos en SQLServer 2005, y hace un par de meses en 2 tablas se han comenzado a cortar unos registros de forma aleatoria, me explico.

Si en un campo antes decia "hola mundo", en la actualidad dice "hola mu" o "hol". Lo mas extraño es que el corte del largo de caracteres es aleatorio y no para todos los registros.

Que me recomiendan hacer para dar con el motivo de esto?. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: incia a descartar, primero valida los atributos del campo, luego inserta un registro desde el SQL Server Management Studio, revisa si tienes triggers sobre ese campo y finalmente revisa las rutinas de tu app que modifican ese campo.

Answer (score 1):

Esto tal como lo mencionas puede deberse a un "bug" involuntario o voluntario del sistema. Para detectar si se trata de un error en el sistema tal como te comentaron, revisar Sp´s, Triggers y Código fuente en general buscando cualquier operación de UPDATE sobre la tabla. Si esto es una tarea de gran envergadura por que no tienes el control sobre todas las rutinas que actualizan la tabla, un truco que podrías implementar sería incorporar un trigger de UPDATE a la tabla y:

1. Verificar si se está modificando la columna en cuestión
2. Si la longitud del valor nuevo es inferior al original, pero el valor nuevo está incluido en el valor original (ej "Hola M" está incluido en "Hola Mundo") generaría un registro en una tabla de log. Se puede registrar hora, hostname, usuario, etc.
3. Con esa información haría una análisis y relevamiento con el usuario para ver que proceso estuvo corriendo.

El problema puede ser un error válido o un evento malicioso, con el registro de dichos eventos al menos puedes iniciar un seguimiento.